# Why 'javascript_pack_tag' only works in the 'body' and not the html 'head' (Rails 6 and webpack)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, turbolinks

In my rails 6 app, my jquery only works when I include `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` in the html 'body' and not the 'head'. I am wondering why this is the case and what I need to do to fix it. This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>TumaJobs</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
    <table class="layout-table">
      <tr class="layout-content-row">
        <td class="layout-content-column">
          <%= yield %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my application.js, I have

```
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
require("jquery")
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("../search")

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

In search.js i have this jquery code

```
  $(".jobs_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($(".jobs_search").attr("action"), $(".jobs_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

With `javascript_pack_tag` in head

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $(".jobs_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($(".jobs_search").attr("action"), $(".jobs_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
})
```

Comment: it works, thanks. If you dont mind can you briefly explain why it works now?

Comment: Probably a bit late to answer, but I believe it has to do with the way Turbolinks emulates SPA behavior. More details here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior